# sed command/shell script to read a specific line and update it if needed

Tags: sh

I have a file whose contents are similar as below.

```
name: MyName
age: 25
subject: Math
```

This file needs to be updated to :

```
name: MyName
age: "25"
subject: Math
```

But the condition is, the sed command/ shell script can run multiple times. But, the double quotes must be added only once.

I wrote a script for it and it works. Want to find a simpler solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="myfile"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ $line  =~ 'age:' ]]
    then
        if ! [[ $line  =~ 'age: "' ]]
        then
            sed 's/\(age:[[:blank:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1"\2"/' -i $FILE
        fi
    fi
done < $FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just run sed from the command line with this slightly altered regex, and it will have the same effect as your script

```
sed -i 's/\(age:[[:blank:]]\+\)\([^"].*\)/\1"\2"/' file
```

It won't match if the first character after the blank space is a double quote, which is what your script checks for.

Tested it and it works for me.